# Static behavior of iterators in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am reading [Learning Python by M.Lutz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449355730) and found bizarre block of code:

```
>>> M = map(abs, (-1, 0, 1))
>>> I1 = iter(M); I2 = iter(M)
>>> print(next(I1), next(I1), next(I1))
1 0 1
>>> next(I2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Why when I call `next(I2)` it happens that iteration is already over? 
Didn't I create two separate instances of `I1` and `I2`. Why does it behave like an instances of a `static` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "static" objects, which don't exist in Python.

`iter(M)` does not create a copy of M. Both I1 and I2 are iterators wrapping the same object; in fact, since `M` is already an iterator, calling `iter` on it just returns the underlying object:

```
>>> iter(M)
<map object at 0x1012272b0>
>>> M
<map object at 0x1012272b0>
>>> M is iter(M)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because in Python 3.X, `map` objects can be iterated over only once. Pointing multiple iterators at it won't reset it to its starting state.

Compare to `map`'s behavior in 2.7. It returns a list, so it can be iterated over multiple times.

```
>>> M = map(abs, (-1, 0, 1))
>>> I1 = iter(M); I2 = iter(M)
>>> print(next(I1), next(I1), next(I1))
(1, 0, 1)
>>> next(I2)
1
```